# How can I call a super class method from a code block in a derived class?

Tags: scala

This question is somewhat hard to summarize. Following code block shows what I want to do.
I have a base class like this:

```
 `class Base {
   def methA:String="ook"
   def methB:Int=1
}
```

Also I have a derived class, where I want each subclass method to call the super class method twice, compare the results and throw an exception on mismatch (this is for a test scenario).

But if I write

```
class Derived extends Base {

  private def callDoublyAndCompare[T](fun:()=>T) : T = {
      val fst=fun()
      val snd=fun()
      if(fst!=snd) throw new RuntimeException(s"Mismatch fst=$fst != snd=$snd")
      snd
  }

  override def methB:Int={
     callDoublyAndCompare(() => super[Derived].methB)
  }
}
```

Then this will not compile. The only way out of this problem sofar has been to extract a method in class *Derived* which only calls the superclass' *methB* and to call this from the lambda call.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I understood you want to call super call method. Hope below is what you want.

You can call that as below with the key word `super` only

`(new Derived).methB` . This will call super call method in `callDoublyAndCompare` twice as per your code .

```
class Derived extends Base {

  private def callDoublyAndCompare[T](fun:()=>T) : T = {
      val fst=fun()
      val snd=fun()
      if(fst!=snd) throw new RuntimeException(s"Mismatch fst=$fst != snd=$snd")
      snd
  }

  override def methB:Int={
     callDoublyAndCompare(() => super.methB) //kept only super
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work for me. The example is incomplete insofar as the Derived class is an inner class of another (scala) class - this is b/c the Derived class is just specific for this test.

Also I ran the test with scala 2.11.4 - I do not know if this has any influence on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The original example was not fully complete insofar as the Derived class was defined as inner class of another scala class.
After I moved out this inner class to the top level, the example from Praveen above suddenly worked.